# Plausible reason why a time machine would be built in a 1990s era sports car?

Tags: time-travel

So let's say we have a hero and a heroine. The hero doesn't own a time machine, but the heroine does and she built her time machine from a modified 1990s era Japanese sports car.

Time travel requires the traveller and the machine to be moving at a certain speed to account for the daily rotation of the Earth (conservation of energy keeps most time machines, including the heroine's time machine, Earth-bound) and works by opening a short-lived wormhole which the machine passes through to the destination time.

Less advanced time machines arrive at the same location on Earth, but the heroine's is fitted with a device that can alter the spatial destination to arrive in a different spatial location. Jumps are limited to a century before our time but have no forward limit.

So why would she build her time machine out of such a car?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. Please consider taking the [tour] to get more familiar with the site. As it stands your question concerns more your story than your world. As such it gets off-topic on this site.

Comment: *the heroine's is fitted with a device that can alter the spatial destination to arrive in a different spatial location* Note that this is required anyway because Earth moves through space and rotates making a very complex positional change for something on the surface to travel in time without ending up in deep space.

Comment: You know, I think I've seen this movie...and it's two sequels. You need a Flux Capacitor in there, too.

Comment: Perhaps the "time drive" works like a Albercurrie drive as it is only a spacetime accelerator; you have to have an initial velocity to travel a significant distance in spacetime. Also you'll want to take the "time drive" with you so you can return to your time. Additionally the spacetime portal created by the "time drive" takes a tremendous amount of energy to maintain (12.1 gigawatts per second). You would only want to open it just long enough to step through. For example the time portal would only have to be open for a tenth of a second for a 13 foot vehicle to travel through at 88MPH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This question is indeed more story-based but i take the bait anyway)*

### The Time Machines charges while drifting.

While any car could do the trick in theory, the time machine needs to accumulate a lot of friction to be triggered, like a car toy with a pullback motor. So the best car for this would be a Toyota Sprinter Trueno (AE86), and the driver would have do drift on the twisting roads to get the apparatus fully charged.

[image]

The Toyota Sprinter Trueno was in production from 1983 to 1987, which is a bit off your era and is mostly [for the joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_D), but you get the idea: the time travel apparatus *has* to work with a car of the 1990s because later cars have too much electronics interfering with the apparatus (like Anti-Braking System if you want to keep the idea of drifting to charge the time travel machine).

Answer (score 3):

They had another vehicle before, but broke it in a previous trip to 1990 Japan. So they got a car of that time, put the rest of the time machine in it and use it ever since.